# Obj-C, catering for 'tap for more rows' and delete without core data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've been adding a temporary row to the end of my table view so I can limit the amount of data loaded / improve the speed of loading the view.

However, I didn't think about the delete feature. Where they swipe right to delete a row..

In my `commitEditingStyle` event I have, my check to see if it is a delete, then delete row from database, `removeObjectAtIndex` from my data array, `beginUpdates`, `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` and if zero items left in my table `insertRowsAtIndexPath` with fade, so that my `no transactions` row will appear then `endUpdates`.

I did think when I add my `tap for more rows` I'd assign the row index to a variable and delete this row first in the `commitEditingStyle` event. However, I'd then have to query my database just to add another row, then add the `tap for more rows` row.

Which seems a lot of work for a quick fix.

Of course, I could just do a `reloadData`, but this seems really bad, but might be my only option.

I do eventually want to move to Core Data, but I really need to get this release out the door, its quite a complicated screen with segmented control for different data views and tap to edit the row in another view.

Can anyone advise me about some kind of trick / event I may have missed or another approach I could quickly use in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make "tap for more" your table footer view instead of another cell. You will have to do this anyway if you move to core data and NSFetchedResultsController since hacking in an extra row becomes very complex then.

Your table footer view will just be a button (or some other view styled how you like it) - this can be created on viewDidLoad and set up with actions etc. It does not form part of your data model at all, so you have nothing extra to do in your datasource methods.

Comment: Surely I'm still going to need to do these row calculations to determine whether to display the footer ?

Comment: Yes, but displaying the footer or not is much easier than adding new rows from within existing row update methods. It gets even easier with the fetched results controller, you only need to look at one delegate method.

Comment: I can see your point and agree, but this doesn't really answer my question. It still doesn't get me round having to get an extra record?

Comment: If this doesn't make sense let me know!

Comment: I've expanded on my answer a bit. Basically your footer view just sits there with whatever you'd put in it (like a button to load the extra rows) so you don't need an extra record in your model to hold it.